# Illustrator: How do you change default Fill/Stroke Colors for the 'D' key?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Pressing D will switch to the default Fill/Stroke colors (which is White Fill / Black Stroke in Illustrator).

I remember having read about a way to define your own default Fill/Stroke colors, but I forgot how – e.g. say I want Transparent Fill and Black Stroke.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, the answer was easy (but hard to recall if you've forgotten it like me):

1. Set your preferred Fill & Stroke.
2. Open the Graphic Styles panel; Window > Graphic Styles.
3. Click the New Graphic Style button.
4. Hold Alt/Opt key and drag the new style onto the default style. (The
   default style is the one having a miniature Fill/Stroke symbol in
   the lower left corner).

Now, pressing 'D' will change all selected objects to the new default style.

A bonus tip: In the Graphic Styles panel, open the Graphic Styles Libraries Menu and choose for example Additive. While having a path selected, Alt-/Opt-click on one of the Additive styles, to add some very interesting effects on your path.

Comment: Hello. Do you have any idea how I can make the default graphic style (the one I made) not reset to the standard white fill / black stroke when I reopen Illustrator?