# How to show grid over elements and center elements to the grid?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, grids

I'm using `Adobe Illustrator CS6`.

I've create some elements, such as a simply gray rectangles with black border.

I've enabled the Grid on the settings (Gridline Every 10px, Subdivisons 10).

Here's the result:

[image]

I'd like to have it to "snap" with the pixel, not in the middle of them.

Also, I'd like to see the grid "over" my elements (such happens in Photoshop); somethings like this (Photoshop counterpart):

[image]

Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu **View** > **Snap to grid**

Menu **Illustrator** > **Preferences** > **Guides & Grid** > Uncheck **Grids in Back**

[image: grid]

Comment: The second point works fine, thanks! For the first, not really. Already tried, it changes nothing :(

Comment: I Guess It is for the stroke ubication: center, outside or inside? Also when selecting the shape, uncheck **Align objects to pixel grid**

Comment: From the transform panel

Comment: Awesome man! Thanks! Also: is there any way to set this properties (stroke ubication) as default? It was center, I'd like to have it "inside" every time.

Comment: Just creating an object style

Comment: MMmmm, what do you mean?

Comment: Check this answer https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/3782/120647 But the stroke position will be not registered at the default style, just as a new style. By the way, did my answer solve your question?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you will got the +1 and accepted! Only a last think (if you can): is there a way to enable the "grid" over a certain zoom? Photoshop do it. So at 100% I won't see any grid, over 500% it appair?

Comment: No as far as I know, just Cmd+' Mac/Ctrl+' Win to show/hide