# How to set the initial color of fill/stroke in the Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Although I saw this [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3693/illustrator-how-do-you-change-default-fill-stroke-colors-for-the-d-key?newreg=7df06c2330104bb8a74eb065719da8d0) and followed the process step-by-step, I have trouble setting the default color of fill/stroke.

I want to set the fill with white(#ffffff) and stroke with black(#000000) in Adobe Illustrator 2024.

When I set them as the basic graph style and restarted the Illustrator, it came back to a slightly different color (i.e., black goes to #231815).

Can anyone give me the solution to this phenomenon?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Sounds to me like your document is in CMYK.  If you want the default black to be #000000 you need an RGB document.  What are you designing for? For print or web, screen, etc?

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment! I'm working on the figures in the journal paper. Since the format for the figure in the author guidelines was not indicated, I basically set the environment as CMYK. I didn't know that the default color of black in CMYK and RGB is different. Thank you for announcing!

Comment: Hex colors are RGB colors. If you are working in CMYK, you really *shouldn't* be using hex values to define *any* color. If you set an RGB/Hex "black" in a CMYK document, it gets converted to a CMYK black based upon the assigned color profiles for the application. If you set a C20M0Y0K100 black in a CMYK file, it'll stay at those values.